# Only get garbage from Shader Storage Block?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, shader-storage-buffer

I have bound the `shader storage buffer` to the `shader storage block` like so

```
GLuint index = glGetProgramResourceIndex(myprogram, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, name);
glShaderStorageBlockBinding(myprogram, index, mybindingpoint);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, mybuffer)
glBindBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, mybindingpoint, mybuffer, 0, 48);
glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 48, &mydata);
```

`mydata` points to a `std::vector` containing 4 `glm::vec3` objects.

Because I bound `48 bytes` as the buffer range I expect `lights[]` to hold `48/(4*3) = 4 vec3s`.

```
layout(std430) buffer light {
    vec3 lights[];
};
```

The element at index `1` in my `std::vector` holds the data `x=1.0, y=1.0, z=1.0`.

But viewing the output by doing

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(lights[1], 1.0);
```

I see **yellow** (`x=1.0, y=1.0, z=0.0`) pixels. This is not what I loaded into the buffer.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

## EDIT

I just changend the shader storage block to

```
layout(std430) buffer light {
    float lights[];
};
```

and output

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(lights[3],lights[4],lights[5],1.0);
```

and it works (white pixels).

If somebody can explain this, that would still be great.

Comment: Please show the exact definition of mydata

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because people don't take this simple advice: [never use a `vec3` in a UBO/SSBO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38172696/734069).

The base alignment of a `vec3` is 16 bytes. *Always*. Therefore, when it is arrayed, the array stride (the number of bytes from one element to the next) is always 16. Exactly the same as a `vec4`.

Yes, `std430` layout is different from `std140`. But it's not that different. Specifically, it only prevents the base alignment and stride of array elements (and base alignment of structs) from being rounded up to that of a `vec4`. But since the base alignment of `vec3` is *always* equal to that of a `vec4`, it changes nothing about them. It only affects scalars and `vec2`'s.

Comment: I will remember your advice for the rest of my life thank so much.